# In Openlayers 3, why are the TMS y-coordinates negative?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

I've been using openlayers 3, 3.17.1, to draw some custom tiles and I noticed that the y coordinate passed to my ol.source.UrlTile subclass' getTile method are negative. Why?

edit: here's how to see what I'm seeing

```
var MyVectorTile = function (options) { 
    ol.source.VectorTile.call(this, options); 
    this.customOption_ = options.customOption;
}; 
ol.inherits(MyVectorTile, ol.source.VectorTile); 
MyVectorTile.prototype.getTile = function (z, x, y, pixelRatio, proj) { 
    console.log(z, x, y); 
    return ol.source.VectorTile.prototype.getTile.call(this, z, x, y, pixelRatio, proj);
}
```

here's another way to see it - add this layer to your map

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: true,
    preload: 16,
    source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
    projection: "EPSG:3857",
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            maxZoom: 22
        }),
    color: 'rgba(255,204,0,1)'
}),
title: 'Ol3 Tile Debug'
});
```

Comment: Is this an obvious or dumb question? A link to the docs would suffice

Comment: There shouldn't be any negative numbers in TMS coordinates, unless you go beyond -180° longitude (which results in a negative x coordinate). I can't find a `getTile()` function in `ol.source.UrlTile` - can you post more about your custom tiles, any code? What reference system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess, after going through ol3 with the JavaScript debugger, is that these are internal coordinates and that `ol.source.TileDebug` will show them unchanged.

In the function `ol.TileUrlFunction.createFromTemplate` there is [this part](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/b25ce407811f86cd533fa9ca2a1d3ddacfff1bb5/src/ol/tileurlfunction.js#L31).

```
var y = -tileCoord[2] - 1;
```

From what I can tell this changes the negative `y` coordinate into a positive one and inserts it into the `{y}` placeholder in a tile URL (they call URLs with placeholders "template"), I tried with OpenStreetMap tiles and the input and output match.

`ol.source.TileDebug` however does not go through this function (there is no "template" URL, and even if you specify one the function is not called) and will just print those internal coordinates on screen.